# App crashes iPhone Sim when selecting from Photo Library

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to use the `UIImagePickerController` to select a photo from the photo library (`UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`).
My problem is, when I select a photo, the application immediately crashes. From the error given below, its attempting to insert `nil` in the `NSDictionary` which returns the photo.

Can't understand why for the life of me. I've seen many crash reports concerning the UIImagePickerController, but none that address this issue. Any ideas out there?

Below is the console output, and further down is my code.

```
2011-10-31 12:29:27.195 LognLoad[49923:7703] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage)'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x02392c99 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x024e05de objc_exception_throw + 47
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0234b3f8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0234b36a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
4   CoreFoundation                      0x02391505 -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:] + 293
5   PhotoLibrary                        0x0b47414e __PLNotifyImagePickerOfImageAvailability_block_invoke_1 + 161
6   PhotoLibrary                        0x0b515ac1 __-[PLAssetsSaver requestImageFromAsset:withFormat:completionBlock:synchronous:]_block_invoke_1 + 45
7   MediaPlayer                         0x0b9e7141 PUTReceivedImageFromAssetURL + 169
8   MediaPlayer                         0x0b9e88c7 do_ReturnImageDataForAssetURL + 225
9   MediaPlayer                         0x0b9e8c4e _XReturnImageDataForAssetURL + 435
10  MediaPlayer                         0x0b9e8a64 PersistentURLTranslatorClient_server + 125
11  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x972d06fb dispatch_mig_server + 232
12  MediaPlayer                         0x0b9e871d __getClientMIGMux_block_invoke_1 + 45
13  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x972aa498 _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 62
14  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9729d3d2 _dispatch_source_invoke + 210
15  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9729bf59 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 163
16  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9729c495 _dispatch_queue_drain + 258
17  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9729bee8 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 50
18  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9729bcfe _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 240
19  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9729b781 _pthread_wqthread + 390
20  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9729b5c6 start_wqthread + 30
)terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Here, I engage the image picker:

```
- (IBAction)getImage
{
// Create image picker controller

self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];

}
```

and here is the callback for the image selection:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
self.photo = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
[[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Probably Photo Library on your simulator is corrupted. Try resetting content and settings on your iPhone Simulator.

Comment: I think you might be right, sgosha. I just added my own photo through the Safari app, and it liked that one. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSString *hour = [components hour] < 10 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%i", [components hour]] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [components hour]];
    NSString *minute = [components minute] < 10 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%i", [components minute]] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [components minute]];
    NSString *second = [components second] < 10 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%i", [components second]] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [components second]];
    NSString *day = [components day] < 10 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%i", [components day]] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [components day]];
    NSString *month = [components month] < 10 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%i", [components month]] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [components month]];
    NSString *year = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [components year]];
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@_%@_%@_%@_%@.png", day, month, year, hour, minute, second];
    NSString  *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@", fileName]];
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];

    if ([picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);

    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I used for both PhotoAlbum and Camera; it saves the picture with a sort of timestamp.

Hope this help you.

Comment: That's pretty handy with the timestamp, but your callback method is actually deprecated now. My application appears to not even make it to the callback, as it throws an error when assembling its arguments. 
Thanks for your prompt reply though :)